# Is it possible to add "Insert Table" to primeFaces Editor

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to add an option "Insert Table" to PrimeFaces Editor.

I am using Mozarra 2.0.3, Prime faces 2.2 RC2, Glass Fish 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible with Primefaces at the moment.

You can paste an html table into the editor but you can't edit the table afterwards ([reported as issue here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2000)). Furthermore I think you don't want to paste an existing table but rather create a new one in the editor.

Comment: I have tried to use CKEditor. But, I am not getting the editor content into backing bean.

Comment: any help on using CKEditor..?